# Strange issue, variables do not exist in context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I think I'm losing my mind...what's going on here?

I've rebuilt, cleaned, built, etc....same thing happens.[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing all breakpoints and setting them again? `agent` doesn't seem to exist and is likely an old breakpoint.

Comment: Clean the solutions tends to clear VS up

Comment: Where is `returnData` defined?  Is it actaully in the same scope?

Comment: Is this a silverlight application? I know the issue from there.

Comment: This is a WCF Service. No matter what I do, I can't get any other variable to work besides `returnData`. The others "don't exist"

Comment: Try deleting your temporary internet files. Helped me last time.

Comment: The compiler may have optimized the variable away. Note that the stores at lines 117, 120, 121, and 122 are all dead, so the compiler may have deleted those lines of code entirely. The variable doesn't exist until line 129 completes.

Comment: @RaymondChen: close. Look at my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. Turns out, either the debugger skips these variables OR asp.net is smart enough to not do anything with the variable UNLESS it has been used later on in the code.

Once I used the variable, ie, `Console.WriteLine(userAgent)`, it showed up.

Comment: Yup, the compiler optimized the variable away since nobody actually used it.

Comment: Yeah, I found this very interesting. While it bugged me (when I didn't understand it), it's actually a very cool and useful 'feature' of the compiler.